# Stacked If_else statements in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I am hoping to code a nested if_else statement, but I am getting an error message.  The error message is unclear. R runs the code, but when I try to call up the new column it says there is an error.

I am attempting to navigate a skip function. The F2_1 questions are the first question, and depending on the answer it will dictate how I use the F2_3 functions.

What did I do wrong here?

```
REALMarriageStatus <- mutate(REALMarriageStatus, IPVOther = 
   if_else((F2_1_1 == 1 & F2_3_1 == 1) | (F2_1_2 == 1 & F2_3_2 == 1) | (F2_1_3 == 1 & F2_3_3 == 1) | (F2_1_4 == 1 & F2_3_4 == 1) | (F2_1_5 == 1 & F2_3_5 == 1) | (F2_1_6 == 1 & F2_3_6 == 1) | (F2_1_7 == 1 & F2_3_7 == 1) | (F2_1_8 == 1 & F2_3_8 == 1) | (F2_1_9 == 1 & F2_3_9 == 1) | (F2_1_10 == 1 & F2_3_10 == 1), "Yes", if_else((F2_1_1 == 1 & F2_3_1 == 2) | (F2_1_2 == 1 & F2_3_2 == 2) | (F2_1_3 == 1 & F2_3_3 == 2) | (F2_1_4 == 1 & F2_3_4 == 2) | (F2_1_5 == 1 & F2_3_5 == 2) | (F2_1_6 == 1 & F2_3_6 == 2) | (F2_1_7 == 1 & F2_3_7 == 2) | (F2_1_8 == 1 & F2_3_8 == 2) | (F2_1_9 == 1 & F2_3_9 == 2) | (F2_1_10 == 1 & F2_3_10 == 2), "No", if_else(F2_1_1 == 2 | F2_1_2 == 2 | F2_1_3 == 2 | F2_1_4 == 2 | F2_1_5 == 2 | F2_1_6 == 2 | F2_1_7 == 2 | F2_1_8 == 2 | F2_1_9 == 2 | F2_1_10 == 2, "No"))
```

I also tried the case_when function but am also getting the error message of: Error: unexpected numeric constant in: "

REALMarriageStatus <- mutate(REALMarriageStatus, IPVOther =
case_when(
(F2_1_1 == 1 & F2_3_1 == 1) | (F2_1_2 == 1 & F2_3_2 == 1) | (F2_1_3 == 1 & F2_3_3 == 1) | (F2_1_4 == 1 & F2_3_4   == 1) | (F2_1_5 == 1 & F2_3_5 == 1) | (F2_1_6 == 1 & F2_3_6 == 1) | (F2_1_7 == 1 & F2_3_7 == 1) | (F2_1_8 == 1 &   F2_3_8 == 1) | (F2_1_9 == 1 & F2_3_9 == 1) | (F2_1_10 == 1 & F2_3_10 == 1) ~ "Yes",
(F2_1_1 == 1 & F2_3_1 == 2) | (F2_1_2 == 1 & F2_3_2 == 2) | (F2_1_3 == 1 & F2_3_3 == 2) | (F2_1_4 == 1 & F2_3_4   == 2) | (F2_1_5 == 1 & F2_3_5 == 2) | (F2_1_6 == 1 & F2_3_6 == 2) | (F2_1_7 == 1 & F2_3_7 == 2) | (F2_1_8 == 1 &   F2_3_8 == 2) | (F2_1_9 == 1 & F2_3_9 == 2) | (F2_1_10 == 1 & F2_3_10 == 2) ~ "No",
(F2_1_1 == 2 | F2_1_2 == 2 | F2_1_3 == 2 | F2_1_4 == 2 | F2_1_5 == 2 | F2_1_6 == 2 | F2_1_7 == 2 | F2_1_8 == 2 |   F2_1_9 == 2 | F2_1_10 == 2) ~ "No")
TRUE ~ as.character(x)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try `case_when` from the `dplyr` package.

Comment: Could you share a little bit of sample data and describe in words what your goal is? Or at least post the error message?

Comment: in the most inner `if_else` function you are missing a statement. It always should read like `if_else(condition, outcome_true, outcome_false)` but you only have `if_else(condition, outcome_true)`

Comment: I'm so sorry @Cettt, which if_else function is missing a statement?  What do I need to add?

Comment: @Gregor Thomas, I am receiving this error message: Error: unexpected symbol in:
" == 2) | (F2_1_9 == 1 & F2_3_9 == 2) | (F2_1_10 == 1 & F2_3_10 == 2), "No", if_else(F2_1_1 == 2 | F2_1_2 == 2 | F2_1_3 == 2 | F2_1_4 == 2 | F2_1_5 == 2 | F2_1_6 == 2 | F2_1_7 == 2 | F2_1_8 == 
REALMarriageStatus"

Comment: @GregorThomas I am attempting to navigate a skip function.  The F2_1 questions are the first question, and depending on the answer it will dictate how I use the F2_3 functions.

Comment: It may be useful to compute the `ifelse` command separately, prior to the `dplyr` statement. This way you can separate any errors from the respective statements.

Comment: Your `case_when` is missing both a comma (before `TRUE~`) and missing a close-paren after `TRUE ~ as.character(x)`.

Comment: @r2evans.  I added the comma before TRUE~, but the closed parenthesis after TRUE ~ as.character(x) resulted in "Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`. x Input `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object. ℹ Input `..2` is `TRUE ~ as.character(x)`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."

Comment: Update: change that last portion to `F2_1_10 == 2) ~ "No", TRUE ~ as.character(x) ) )`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do anything. I get the error message "Error: Problem with mutate() input IPVOther. x object "x" not found